# How to Call Multiple Methods in a Switch Case in Java

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

I'm learning how to build a table in Java with MVC and I am trying to have a switch case that both performs changes to the data in the model and also calls a method like this

```
 public void update()
    {   model.fireTableDataChanged();   }
```

to update the data presented on the table.

Here is the switch case

```
 public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
    {   switch(col)
        {   case 0: return row;
            case 1:  return car.on(car.stops());
            default: return "";   }  
        }
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated and if you need to see more of the code to help you answer my question I will provide it.

Comment: Show your current switch code and explain what problems you're having with it.

Comment: Have a look at [the docs regarding the switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), that should help you.

Comment: @hungryghost I've added the switch case, the table (car.on) displays where a person will get on the car, car.stops shows the stops of the car.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? I'm still learning the ins and outs a bit.

Comment: Switch is just another way to control code blocks. You can have multiple lines of code in each case. I'll post an answer with example code.

Comment: break statement is missing

Comment: I think return automatically breaks, but yeah, break is the standard way of doing switch/case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've formatted your code differently. Hopefully, it makes it easier to understand the multiple statements. Try something like this:

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    switch(col) {   
        case 0:
            // You can add any number of statements here.
            ...
            update();
            return row;
        case 1:
            ...
            update();
            return car.on(car.stops());
        default:
            ...
            update();
            return "";
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for this. It produces a loop, is there anyway to put a break after the return statement?

Comment: Return exits the method completely, so no code inside the method will run after you return. If you're having recursion and/or looping problems, that's probably something outside your method.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be under the incorrect understanding that cases end at the first semicolon. This is incorrect. Cases don't end until you end them with the close brace for the overall switch statement, or until you include a break. Between the case and the end of the case, you can have any number of lines of code that do (pretty much) anything you want.

Think of a switch almost like a function, where the only* way to exit the function is to reach a break statement, return statement, or the close brace at the end, in exactly the same way that you exit functions with return and reaching the end of the function.

```
switch(condition) {
    case 1:  fcnOne();
    case 2:  fcnTwoA(); fcnTwoB();
    case 3:  fcnThree; break;
    default: fcnFour();
}
```

If the condition is 1 then fcnOne() is called. There is no break in fcnOne(), so the code continues on into case 2. This is often called falling through. fcnTwoA() is then called. The code continues to the next instruction, which is to call fcnTwoB(). The next instruction is fcnThree(). Finally, we encounter a break statement, which exits the switch block.

---

Yes, I am intentionally ignoring exceptions, System.exit(), and return values for non-void functions.

Comment: This is a good example of case use. You can omit breaks/returns between cases if you want to have more complex control flow (e.g. Case A do 1,2,3; Case B do 2,3; Case C do only 3; etc.). The more "basic" way to do it is to have single case code blocks for each case (plus maybe a default case). But this is more of an "advanced" use. Also, read the docs. They're very helpful!